# Error when activating SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm using SharePoint Online Plan E3.
When I activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure in Site collection features, it always return error:

> Server encountered an internal error.

I've tried again many times but still the same.

How can I activate this features on SharePoint Online?

Comment: Does this happen on all your site collections? Are you able to create new site collections with the Publishing Site Template?

Comment: Even when I create new site collection, it still happens

Comment: The best option probably is to raise a ticket with MS about this. Since SharePoint Online is maintained by MS itself.

Comment: Hmm. That's weird. I can activate this feature now without problem.